# Cloudbuild.yaml command with nested quotes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am trying to run the following command found at http://blog.wrouesnel.com/articles/Totally%20static%20Go%20builds/:

`CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -ldflags '-extldflags "-static"' .`

The two inner layers of quotes are tripping me up. How to deal with this in a `cloudbuild.yaml` file?

Escaping quotes don't seem to work:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/go'
  args: ['build', '-o', 'main', '-ldflags', "'-extldflags \"-static\"'", '.']
  env:
  - 'GOOS=linux'
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**

There is no need for such quotes. See comment in Github here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/issues/146#issuecomment-337890587

===

**Original Answer**

Well, to quote `'` within `'`-quoted strings, use `''` as per YAML specification:

http://yaml.org/spec/current.html#id2534365

e.g. `'here''s to a toast!'`

For the above args, it would be:

```
['build', '-o', 'main', '-ldflags', '''-extldflags "-static"''', '.']
```

Whether or not the command works within Cloud Builder is beyond the scope of this question.